# Distributing a python script that relies on external modules

Tags: python, deployment, module

Are there any easy solutions to ensure that users of my Python script will have minimal trouble ensuring that they have the same modules available to import?

For example, if my script relies on Flask, what can I do to streamline another user's acquiring Flask?

Comment: Read up on [setuptools](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools) dependencies and versioning. It implements dependency checks and downloads any missing packages (when there's an internet connection) .

Comment: @isedev thanks!  That sounds like an answer.